# Codeception/Selenium: setting Firefox parameters

Tags: selenium, firefox, codeception

I'm using Selenium with Codeception to crawl a website and Firefox gives me this error message
"A script on this page may be busy, or it may have stopped responding..."

So I need to set the `dom.max_chrome_script_run_time` and the `dom.max_script_run_time value` to 0 for Selenium.

I created a new profile with a `pref.js` like this

```
user_pref("browser.download.lastDir", "/tmp/justtotest");
user_pref("dom.max_chrome_script_run_time", 0);
user_pref("dom.max_script_run_time", 0);
```

And I changed my `acceptance.suite.yml` like this

```
class_name: AcceptanceTester
modules:
    enabled:
        - Filesystem
        - WebDriver:
            url: 'http://www.website.com'
            browser: firefox
            connection_timeout: 600
            request_timeout: 600
            capabilities:
                 firefox_profile: '/tmp/profile.zip.b64'
```

During the test when I enter `about:config` in the address bar the `browser.download.lastDir` has correctly been updated but the `dom.max_chrome_script_run_time` and the `dom.max_script_run_time` still have default value.

It seems Selenium overwrites these values when the test starts.

Is there a way to set those parameters for Selenium or am I missing something?

Thanks for help